# Implement OAuth2 flow with authenticated code grant type using REST API without front end

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

I have to use Oauth2.0 with grant type "authorization code". The resource server is different party and my side will be the client. I am using the web browser and getting the code manually. From the code I am getting the access token and able to call the API manually. This same process I will have to do using REST api I don't have any front end for my application as it's monthly cron job. I have searched but could not find any examples related to this using REST API. Will it be possible to implement this using REST API ? Which approach will be suited here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is based on different `grants` or `flows` for different types of client:

- A web browser should use the [Authorization Code Grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1)
- A Cron job should use the [Client Credentials Grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4) and just send an HTTP request similar to that below:

```
curl -k -X POST \
  https://localhost:8443/oauth/v2/oauth-token \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=server&client_secret=Secr3t!'
```

The component that handles all of these messages is the Authorization Server (AS). For your Cron job you need to get the other party to configure an OAuth Client with that flow in their AS, as in [this article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/client-credentials/).

You cannot reliably use code flow in a Cron job, since it involves browser actions such as following redirects and autoposting forms. The API owners need to provide you with an option suited to your client.